# how to make a operator have an explicit parameter c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std-function, explicit

consider some code:

```
void foo() { }
bool bar() { return true; }

struct S
{
    void operator=(std::function<void()> f){f();};
    void operator=(std::function<bool()> f){f();};      
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s = foo; // ok
    s = bar; // error: use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous
}
```

How can I make this example unambiguous?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how does `S = bool()` match the `void` version of `operator=`?  And I assume by `S = void()` and `S = bool()` you actually mean something more like `S s; s = foo;` and `S s; s = bar;`, right?

Comment: Can you make this an [mcve] and include the error message that you are getting?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it does, because `std::function` does type erasure

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I do mean something more like `S s; s = foo;` and `S s; s = bar;` as for how `S = bool()` matches `void operator=(std::function<void()> f){};` I am not sure but when I execute the code it gives me I get the `error ambiguous overload for 'operator='`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `std::function<void(Args...)>` is allowed to discard return types - so both `std::function<void()>` and `std::function<bool()>` can be constructed from a `bool(*)()`. The latter will forward through the return from `bar`, but the former will just discard it. That's perfectly valid behavior, but causes this to be ambiguous.

What you probably want is to avoid `std::function` altogether:

```
template <class F>
void operator=(F f) { f(); }
```

Comment: what if I want to have each function return something different? Explicit template specialization would be my solution but then I have to use plain function pointers right?

Comment: @Julian That depends entirely on what it is you actually want to do.